# OnClick event is now working on asp net core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, onclick, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a page that receives data from a database, and for each record it creates a row () on my page. Here is the HTML code:

```
    @foreach (var item in @Model.veterinarios)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="custom-checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="options[]" value="1">
                                            <label for="checkbox1"></label>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>@item.IdVeterinario</td>
                                    <td>@item.Nombre</td>
                                    <td>@item.Apellido</td>
                                    <td>@item.consultorio</td>
                                    <td>  
    
      <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal" onclick="@{guardarIdVet(@item.idVeterinario);}"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
     <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal" ><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
    
                              
                                    </td>
    
                                </tr>
                            }
```

So the last  has two elements that open up a div that is at the end of my code. What i would like to do is to SAVE the @item.IdVeterinario on a variable in my controller (model).

Below is the C# code in the HTML view:

```
    @functions
    {
        public void guardarIdVet(int a)
        {
            
            Model.valor= a;
        }
    }
```

When the page runs for the first time, that OnClick event fires 3 times. But when i click on it it doesnt do anything.

I ve tried with asp:LinkButton and still does not work. Funny thing is that yesterday it worked and i changed NOTHING

Comment: Why don't you use `onclick()` to call a function in js?

Comment: Because i am  suppose to use only C#

Comment: In general we use `@onclick` to call the method in `@{xxxx}` in razor component.